# I can't figure why my code does not work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why 'chances--' does not work like I want? I want to subtract only 1. It subtracts the length of the word. Also it subtracts even if the letter match. I tried to console.log 'chances' after the subtract and it logs:
6,
5,
4,
3,
2,
1,
0
And then it continues to subtract the length of the 'word' every time I submit the form.

```js
function createBoxes(word) {
  var bigDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('game')[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    bigDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
  };
};
var selectedWord = 'Romania'.toLowerCase();
createBoxes(selectedWord);

window.onload = function() {
  var chances = document.querySelector('#chances').innerText = selectedWord.length
  var form = document.querySelector('.form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // You have to enter one letter
    var selectedLetter = document.querySelector('#selectText').value;
    if (selectedLetter.length > 1) {
      alert('You have to enter one letter')
    }

    // Check if the letter match
    var allNewDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.game div');
    for (var i = 0; i < allNewDivs.length; i++) {
      if (selectedWord[i] === selectedLetter) {
        allNewDivs[i].innerText = selectedLetter.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        chances--
      }
    };
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hangman</title>
    <style media="screen">
      .game > div {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin-right: 3px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="count">
      <h3>Chances remained: <strong id="chances"></strong></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="game"></div>

    <form class="form">
        <input id='selectText' type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function createBoxes(word) {
      var bigDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('game')[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        bigDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
      };
    };
    var selectedWord = 'Romania'.toLowerCase();
    createBoxes(selectedWord);

    window.onload = function() {
      var chances = document.querySelector('#chances').innerText = selectedWord.length;
      var form = document.querySelector('.form');

      form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        // You have to enter one letter
        var selectedLetter = document.querySelector('#selectText').value;
        if (selectedLetter.length > 1) {
          alert('You have to enter one letter')
        }

        // Check if the letter match
        var found = false;
        if(chances >0){
            var allNewDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.game div');
            for (var i = 0; i < allNewDivs.length; i++) {
              if (selectedWord[i] === selectedLetter) {
                allNewDivs[i].innerText = selectedLetter.toUpperCase();
                found = true;
              }       
            };
            if(!found){ 
                chances--;
                document.querySelector('#chances').innerText = chances;
            }
        }else{
            alert('you have reached the limit');
        }

      });
    }
```

Comment: It would have been useful an explanation of your code and about what was the error...

Answer (score 0):

Because `chance--` is inside the `for` loop that checks letter by letter. So it reduces once for every letter